# MySql database connection issues

Tags: mysql, authentication, plesk

I've got a reseller account on shared Plesk hosting but no root access. I have a site and a subdomain that has a database but I hadn't had a chance to write the code that connects it. I recently needed to move the site & database into its own Plesk subscription and that involved adding the GitHub libraries back in and running composer through Plesk.

FF to today and I'm trying to connect to the database. I can get to it through SqlYog but not through pdo - I'd get authentication errors. I added mysqli, same problem.

I added a new database and new user to see if the move was the problem. Now all I get are 500 errors. Nothing is being written to the error logs.

MySql 5.5
PHP 7.2

Is this a Plesk problem or something I can fix?

Here's my code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$set = 2;
$method = 1;

$host = 'localhost';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

if ($set === 1) {
    $db = 'PermaDb';
    $user = 'permaname';
    $pass = '123456';  // proper password but not special chars
} else {
    $db = 'TestDb';
    $user = 'testname';
    $pass = '654321';
}

if ($method === 1) {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

//$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
    ];
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo '<li>' . $e->getMessage();
        echo '<li>' . $e->getCode();
    }
} else {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<li>Mysqli: Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    } else {
        echo '<li>Mysqli: Connected';
    }
    echo '<li>' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the exact authentication error? How did you move the database? What do you mean by a 'new database'? 500 errors will show up in the web server logs. What error is there? Is there a mysql error log and what are its contents?

Comment: My hosting panel allows me to have more than one database so I created a second one. I moved the site and the database using Plesk's control panel functionality.

I don't have a MySQL error log and nothing is getting written to the error log. I have just spotted one error in the pdo part but now I'm getting a blank screen and still nothing in the error log.